# Converting from on type of list to another type

Tags: c#, list, typeconverter

I have two classes - `Record` and `RecordModified`

```
public  class Record
{
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public int FacilityID { get; set; }
    public int NewAID { get; set; }
    public string OldID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int SyncStatusID { get; set; }
    public int RecordTypeID { get; set; }//RecordTypeID is integer here.

}
```

The second class

```
public  class RecordModified
{
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public int FacilityID { get; set; }
    public int NewAID { get; set; }
    public string OldID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int SyncStatusID { get; set; }
    public string RecordTypeText { get; set; }//RecordTypeText is string here.
 }
```

I have a list of Record with at least 100 `Record` objects, now I have to convert the `List<Record>` into `List<RecordModified>`. The `RecordTypeID` property of the `Record` class has to be converted to the property `RecordTypeText` of `RecordModified` using `enum`s which are in a different class.

Code snippet on how I'm trying to convert:

```
 foreach(Record r in List<Record>)
 {
   switch(r.RecordTypeID)
   {
     case (int)MyEnum.One:
     listofRecordModified.Add(new RecordModified{RecordTypeID=r.RecordTypeID,...,**RecordTypeText=(MyEnum.One).ToString()})** // Notice this
     break;
     ...........//75 more cases.
    }
```

This solution works fine, but the problem is lot of codes and I don't think its efficient.  There must be some better way to do that. Please suggest.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman ...Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use ConvertAll Method along with this

```
List<Record> t = new List<Record>();

            var result = t.ConvertAll(x => new RecordModified()
                {
                    RecordTypeText = ((MyEnum)x.RecordTypeID).ToString()
                });
```

Comment: the solution worked great, thanks. Can you please suggest a good tutorial to understand lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

If your sole problem is the conversion of the index of an `enum` to its text, you could use `GetNames` and use the index of the to get the name of the `enum` value used.

```
string text = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum))[r.RecordTypeID];
```

This way, you don't need the `switch` statement, and you can revert to one line only.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the You can do using the `(MyEnum)x.RecordTypeID` to cast the integer value to matching `enum` value. and then use that `.ToString()` to get string value.`Linq Lambda expressions` as below,

```
var result = RecordList.Select(x=>new RecordModified{
                              RecordTypeID=x.RecordTypeID,
                               ...,
                              RecordTypeText=((MyEnum)x.RecordTypeID).ToString()
                            });
```

You can also use the `ConvertAll` as,

```
var result = RecordList.ConvertAll(x => new RecordModified()
                {
                    RecordTypeText = ((MyEnum)x.RecordTypeID).ToString()
                });
```

`Select` is a `LINQ extension` method and works on all `IEnumerable<>` objects whereas `ConvertAll` is implemented only by `List<>`. The `ConvertAll` method exists since .NET 2.0 whereas `LINQ` was introduced with 3.5.

You should favor `Select` over `ConvertAll` as it works for any kind of list, but they do the same basically.

Comment: the solution worked great, thanks. Can you please suggest a good tutorial to understand lambda expression.

Comment: @dividedbyzero: What about the [C# programming guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have each switch statement for each MyEnum value?
That is a lot of repeated code, that's true.

Why don't you just convert int to text value directly?

You can do it like this for more readability

```
 foreach(Record r in List<Record>)
      {
          MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)r.RecordTypeID;
         string stringValue = myEnum .ToString();
         listofRecordModified.Add(new   RecordModified{RecordTypeID=r.RecordTypeID, ...,**RecordTypeText=stringValue })** // Notice this

        }
```